# how to replace n-th occurrence in Go

Tags: go, replace, slice

how to replace a func function (s, old, new [] bytes, n int) [] bytes which, given three
slice of bytes, s, old, new, and an integer n, returns a slice corresponding to s in which the
n-th occurrence of old is replaced with new. In case this occurrence does not exist,
the function returns s without changing it? thanks

````
import (

    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    s := os.Args[1]
    old := os.Args[2]
    new := os.Args[3]
    n, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[4])
    fmt.Println(s)
    replaced := replace([]byte(s), []byte(old), []byte(new), n)
    fmt.Println(string(replaced))
}

func replace(s, old, new []byte, i int) (replaced []byte) {

}```
````

Comment: Hint: search for the nth occurrence, and slice the input there. Concatenate the prefix, new string and suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a combinaison of `bytes.SplitAfter`, which will split your original string after the separator (old for you), `bytes.Replace()` on the N element of your slice, and then, `bytes.Join` to re-compose your original string.

You should check for the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Replace) which is pretty clear :)

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := []byte("oink oink oink oink")
    old := []byte("k")
    new := []byte("X")

    splitedStr := bytes.SplitAfter(str, old)
    splitedStr[2] = bytes.Replace(splitedStr[2], old, new, -1)


    fmt.Printf("%s", bytes.Join(splitedStr, []byte("")))
}
```